# Rails The action 'show' could not be found for CommentsController error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to follow the rails getting started guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html to create a blog for a small website i've developed in rails

I've read many similar questions on SO but i'm still not able to figure out why i keep getting the error `The action 'show' could not be found for CommentsController error` when trying to destroy a comment as done in the guide.

Here's my link in my html.erb code:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment], :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete?', :method => :delete %>
```

My template header has these lines

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js", "rails", "superfish", "jquery.quicksand", 'slides.min.jquery' %>
```

My gemfile contains this:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

I've also noticed that when i load the page with the destroy comment link on it, there is this error in the firebug console:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/assets/rails.js"
```

Any help on figuring out this issue is appreciated. Let me know if you want anything else posted.

**EDIT**:
Manifest file.

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Routes.rb

Allthingswebdesign::Application.routes.draw do

```
get "about/index"
get "home/index"
get "portfolio/index"
get "contact/index"
post "contact/create"
get "contact/new"
get "posts/index"
get "posts/new"
```

resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

root :to => 'home#index'
end

Comment: have your run bundle install since adding the gem?

Comment: Yes I have run bundle install after adding the gem.

Comment: without the rails.js file the link will not be transformed to use the delete method and will indeed route to show. Just wanted to confirm that loading this asset IS the problem

Comment: If you are using the asset pipeline then you should be using the manifest to define all the javascript include tags.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the rails.js file and the asset pipeline and manifest? I'm new to rails. Isn't the jquery-rails gem what includes the rails.js file?

Comment: You can look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Ok so after readying the asset_pipeline guide and some other stuff on the web, I shouldn't actually need the rails.js file anymore so i removed `rails` from my javascripts_include_tag. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: can you post your routes.rb file?

Comment: hmm, it looks ok. although `resources :posts` should take care of `get "posts/index"` and `get "posts/new"` so I think you can take those out. Have you tried restarting your server?

Comment: Yep i've restarted my server and removed both of those post routes. Stil the same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was there a reason that you got rid of the javascript include in the tutorial? (not a snarky question - just curious). Try adding this line to `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.`:

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

The problem you are having really smells like the javascript function that fakes sending a DELETE request is missing/malfunctioning.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. I added this and it worked great. I'm guessing i accidently removed this when i was putting my template into rails code.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your routes

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Comment: Now i get an error msg when clicking the delete link that says `No route matches [GET] "/posts/2/comments/1"`. Do i need to add something to my routes file?

Comment: well, for some reason, you're comment delete link is sending a get request instead of delete. I'm not sure why, but I think if you added something to your routes like `match 'posts/:post_id/comments/:id' => 'comments#destroy'` that will force the link to use the destroy method of your comments_controller.rb. Sorry, this is more of a work around instead of "the correct way" but everything in the code you posted looks good to me.